# How to improve inefficient duplicated for statement in java

Tags: java, for-loop, performance

I am using a duplicate for statement for some reason, but somehow I feel inefficient. The reasons why I use duplicated for statement is below.

- I got 'channel' data, which is a List of Channel information
- Channel Information is '`Map<String, Object>`' type which has many elements
- There is another list of `Map<String, Object>` which represent program information
- What I need to do in insert a program in to each channels

Source code is below

```
public static void injectProgram2Channel (
            List<Map<String, Object>> channelList, List<Map<String, Object>> programList) throws Exception {
        for(Map<String, Object> channel : channelList){
            String serviceId = channel.get("serviceId").toString();
            ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> programsForChannel = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
            for(Map<String, Object> program : programList){
                if(serviceId.equals(program.get("serviceId").toString())){
                    programsForChannel.add(program);
                }
            }
            channel.put("programs", programsForChannel);
        }
    }
```

I do not want to iterate all of this List, since each List has many elements. How can I improve its performance?

- Channel List has around 500 Elements
- Program List has around 2000 Elements

(I need solution which does not using duplicated for statement)

Comment: You are right. There is a way to do this by looping through all the programs once. I'll stop there, but feel free to ask additional questions. I don't want you to skip the fun of figuring it out yourself :)

Comment: Are you suggesting skipping over certain elements? Unless you want to change the functionality of the method, you must iterate through each value in the `Map`.

Comment: You've got your data structures wrong. You need a `Map<ServiceID, ...>.` @Human There is no 'iterat[ing] through each value in the Map' here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask yourself the question: does it matter how fast it is. If it doesn't, don't make code more complex. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil".

Once you have confirmed that performance is relevant, try to create a benchmark e.g. using JMH and with that in place, start to optimise.

Comment: While I agree with this, there is nothing wrong with being mindful of how your code could be more efficient *without* making it more complicated. Sometimes we overcomplicate and need to go back to clean up.

Comment: Usual [partial and out-of-context quotation from Knuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize). I suggest you look up what he *really* said, and what he was talking about when he said it. This case does not apply. The answer is clearly a better data structure, which would yeild a major improvement, not a minor one, and there is nothing wrong with looking into that. Most software design *starts* with the data structures.

Comment: It depends. I do performance tuning/distributed and concurrent computing for a living. Introducing complexity early at points where it doesn't make sense, only obfuscates the problem. So just do the simplest thing that will work, unless you can prove it is relevant to performance.

Comment: when something really needs to be fast, e.g the new Hazelcast engine we are working on, it is a lot easier to start with something basic but fast and then slowly add features, then to tune a complex system. So here you do look at good data-structures, amount of locking/blocking, object litter, memory access patterns etc. 

But I don't have the impression the problem of the user falls in that category.

Comment: If someone on our team would add complexity that isn't backed-up by a benchmark or has no practical value in production, the code will ber rejected; you don't want to carry weight for something you don't use. If the code change doesn't add any complexity and adds clarity, I'm perfectly fine with adding that to the codebase.

Comment: Designing a correct data structure isn't 'adding complexity', it is an essential part of program design, and this one is obviously mis-designed.

Comment: I agree with you that selecting the correct data-structure is important. So we are on the same page here.

But I would let a benchmark drive the choice for which data-structure is the most effective.

Answer (score 0):

```
Channel List has around 500 Elements
Program List has around 2000 Elements
```

Those are really small in real world applications. You shouldn't worry if you have only two nested for loops for that amount of data.

Comment: If that is just string it is small, however when I combine those two list it occupies more than 200MB. So I am little bit worry about to being expanded(For Instance, Channels can be added.).

Answer (score 0):

As hinted a possible option that *may* or *may not* make sense in your case would be to just group the programs by **serviceId** into a new `Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>>` and lookup the **programs** when needed.

```
public static Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>> buildProgramList (
        List<Map<String, Object>> programList) throws Exception {

    Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>> programsByServiceId = new HashMap<>();

    for(Map<String, Object> program : programList){
        String serviceId = program.get("serviceId").toString();
        if(programsByServiceId.containsKey(serviceId)){
            programsByServiceId.get(serviceId).add(program);
        } else {
            programsByServiceId.put(serviceId,
                    new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(){{
                add(program);
            }});
        }
    }
    return programsByServiceId;
}
```

Once this structures is built, just retrieve your **programs** for a **channel** by calling

```
List<Map<String, Object>> programs = programsByServiceId.get(channel.get("serviceId").toString());
```

And if you want to get extra fancy you could lazy load the results in to the **channel**. Something like

```
if (channel.get("programs") == null) 
    channel.put("programs", programsByServiceId.get(channel.get("serviceId").toString());
return channel.get("programs");
```

This would defer the upfront cost and spread it out.

When this *might* make sense.  If there are certain **channels** that are looked up more often than others for their **program** list.

When this does not make sense. All of the **channels** are requested their list of **programs** immediately or *soon* after. (like if you are just going to serialize all of the channels and their programs).

Comment: There is a way to do this with the OP's data structure. And the hinted approach makes sense *all* the time as it is O(n) instead of O(n^2)